# How To Create Folder In Linux With Permisson

Tags: linux, centos

Hi I want to create folder in Centos in / with permission so that any user can create folder and file in that folder.

Answer (score 1):

use `mkdir` to create the folder

```
 mkdir -m 777 yourfolder
```

to give access to a specific  users

```
 chown <some_user>: yourfolder
```

and if you want to added the user to the group associated with the folder

```
usermod -a -G groupname <some_user>
```

but in your case the first methode will do it for you

Comment: hey i want to give permission to all user.?

Comment: @Vivek you need to specifie the user , or you can share the folder on the network its up to you

Comment: Giving access to the users is unnecessary when the folder is world writable.

Comment: `-G` in `usermod` requires a groupname, not a foldername.

Comment: @alvits true  , what i wanted to say is he could either give acess to a specif user or guarante a full acess to the folder , i will edit my answer , thanks for pointing out the error

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Using `mkdir`

```
mkdir -m 777 folder_name
```

OR

```
mkdir -m a=rwx folder_name
```

where `-m` stands for `setting file **mode**` that resolves to permissions on the directory and `777` or `a=rwx` ( all / everyone = rwx ) means that everyone can read, write and execute.

#### 2. Using `install`

```
install -d -m 0777 folder_name
```

where `-d` means **directory** and `-m` means **set permission mode** , same as in mkdir command.

#### 3. Write a shell script or `function() in .bashrc`

- You can write a simple shell script like this

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  mkdir "$1"
  chmod 777 "$1"
  ```

  Save it with any name say mkdirwap and then make it executable by running `chmod` and run the script.

  ```
  chmod u+x mkdirwap
  ./mkdirwap your_folder
  ```
- Or write a function() in .bashrc like this

  ```
  mkdirwap ()
  {
      mkdir "$1"; chmod 777 "$1"
  }
  ```

  OR

  ```
  mkdirwap () { install -d -m "$1" }
  ```

  where in both cases `"$1" refers to 1st parameter` passed to function, which in this case is your_folder (name of the folder).

  When done, save file .bashrc and source it by typing

  ```
  source ~/.bashrc
  ```

  OR

  ```
  . ~/.basrc
  ```

  and you are good to go.

Feel free to add-in more details to answer.

Comment: Nicely formatted and comprehensive. You should mention that without sticky bit, everyone will be able to delete anybody's files. You should encourage the use of sticky bit in a world writable directories.

Answer (score 0):

use mkdir as below

```
mkdir -m -a=rwx yourfolder
```

Answer (score 0):

use **mkdir** to create the folder

```
mkdir -m rwx yourfolder
```